# VaR for Options portfolio

Tags: options, portfolio, historical-data, value-at-risk

I'm asked to estimate VaR for Options portfolio. Firstly, I wanna try to estimate VaR for AAPL stock european call option using Historical Simulation but I can't find any Historical Data. I tried Google but I don't see a clear time series. Could any please share a link?

Answer (score 2):

If you looking for historical data of a stock. I will recommend you these three websites:
[Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL),
[Wall Street Journal](https://quotes.wsj.com/AAPL), and
[Investing.com](https://www.investing.com/)

Comment: You can't find any historical data for what? The key parameter for the Black Scholes formula is Implied Vol. I do not think past values of IV for AAPL options are available in any public free database. (If this is a classroom project you might compute historical vol yourself instead, using the price series. Of course that is not how options are actually priced, but it would be a start).